# convert promise resolve to readable data in the called function

Tags: javascript, node.js

im doing some online test , which i need to call a function , inside that function send an http request to an api and return its response

```
function callapi()
{
    require('https').get(`https://example.com/api/getdata`, (res) =>
    {
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      res.on('data', function (body)
      {
        var data = JSON.parse(body);
        return(data);
      });
    });

}
```

sine the call is async i need to wrap it inside a promise so the function would return after reciving response

```
function callapi()
{
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject)
  {
    require('https').get(`https://example.com/api/getdata`, (res) =>
    {
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      res.on('data', function (body)
      {
        var data = JSON.parse(body);
        resolve(data);
      });
    });
  })

}
```

here is the problem , since resolve response is not readable if i console.log it i get

```
console.log(callapi());
Promise { <pending> }
```

i need to call it like

```
callapi.then(function (result)
{
  console.log(result)
})
```

so i can have a readable data , but the test doesn't allow me to change its structure and requires my function to return the data without needing to use `.then` to see the result  ... so my question is how can return the data from function without needing to using `.then` to see the output

** ps : i dont have to use promise , any other solution will work **

Comment: *"so my question is how can return the data from function without needing to using `.then` to see the output"* You can't. What kind of online test is this?

Comment: @FelixKling is correct. The only alternative is `async`/`await` but that's just using `.then` under the hood. And you still get a promise as the return value.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try to use `async` and `await`.

eg: `function async callapi()`

and `return await new Promise(function (resolve, reject)`

Comment: If any the syntax is `async function callapi()`. But an `async` function just returns a promise. Since the function already returns a promise, there is no need to add `async` or `await`. In other words, `function foo() { return new Promise(...); }` and `async function foo() { return await return Promise(...); }` are equivalent for all intents and purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the promise, then you can make a sperate function(which performs the operation on returned data) and passed it to callapi function as a parameter.

```js
function callapi(callback)
{
    require('https').get(`https://example.com/api/getdata`, (res) =>
    {
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      res.on('data', function (body)
      {
        var data = JSON.parse(body);
        //return(data);
        callback(data); 
      });
    });

}
```

Comment: how can i get the return with this solution ? i need to call the function and get a result without any other steps ... i can add another function but i have to call `callapi` first

Comment: when you are calling the function just pass the callback as params to perform the operation on returned data.
Inside the callapi function, once the request is completed and response is received  then callback function will execute with received data.

Comment: iu know that , but it wouldn't return the function result to the caller ... i need these lines give me the result 

`var result = callapi(); console.og(result);`